# Taxi not accepting payment by credit card (although advertised)

Tags: uk, taxis

Tonight, I took a taxi from point A to point B (both being in the same city, Liverpool, UK), but I only had 5 pounds on me, so I asked the driver if I could pay with a card, because it was advertised inside the taxi that I could, to which he responded that he doesn't take cards but the other driver with whom he shares the car does. What he did was, stop the meter at about 5.25-5.50 and drove a few more meters.

I previously told him that I only had 5 pounds on me. I offered to go inside my house grab some change, but he said that it's fine, so he accepted the five pounds, and I left.

Is this alright?

I'm not thinking of reporting him at all, I'm worried he might report me.

This happened in Liverpool, UK.

Comment: You can make a complaint to the taxi company. It is not supposed to happen, but it is very common. The drivers resent cards only accept them to stay competitive with Uber and Lyft. But you came to an agreement, £5 for a £5.50 journey, can't complain too much. Your other option in future is to check before you get in, or say "card is all I have" and see if the machine magically bursts into life. Or use an app-based taxi solution of course....

Comment: @Calchas Can they make some kind of complaint to me? I didn't get any receipts.

Comment: "_I_ don't take cards" is much different than "The equipment needed to accept a credit card is not present in this taxi". Though it might be a violation of his contract with his employer.

Comment: I have to say it's unclear to me why a driver would accept cash totalling less than the metered fare rather than a credit card for the full amount (on which he might reasonably get a tip). A cash payment off the meter would obviously give him the opportunity to pocket the fare, but once it's on the meter that's pretty unlikely.

Comment: @DJClayworth If he is not in the habit of paying all his taxes, a cash payment is off the record. There is also a fee for credit card transactions, although it isn't as if processing cash is fee-free.

Comment: @WadeTyler It's normal to round taxi fares up or down. There is no complaint to be made against you.

Comment: Equipment may also be simply broken.   Or perceived to be broken because of failing when last used, perhaps because of a signal issue.

Comment: @Calchas: **Don't bother making a complaint to the taxi company.** Make a complaint to the Carriage Commission for Liverpool, or whatever municipality. OP can easily find them via Google. Tada! [Liverpool City Council online taxi complaint form](https://contact.liverpool.gov.uk/cus/servlet/ep.app?type=UF297081&srvId=UF297929&ut=X)

Comment: You seem to be concerned that you will be pursued over this. You won't be. You have already done more than is required by paying anything. If he's supposed to take a credit card and he doesn't, once you've offered payment via the card, that's it: if he refuses it, bad luck.

Comment: Pursued for what and by whom? As if there is an agency that chases up 20 to 50 pence worth of unpaid taxi fares which have already been agreed upon by passenger and driver.

Comment: They advertise that they take credit cards but won't take a credit card payment at the end of the ride? Sounds like you got a free ride.

Comment: "Is this alright?" No, I would say the taxi company absolutely wouldn't like such behavior of the driver. Neither not supporting what they advertise nor especially driving you additional road for free. Putting that aside, what else you expect to get answered? You seem to be alright with it, the driver seems to be alright with this, so yeah, except the company everyone should be fine.

Comment: It's important to note that in many countries, there's a difference between 'card' and 'credit card'. The general 'card' can often be understood to mean 'bank card' but that's quite different from a credit card. In my country at least, to my knowledge payment using a bank card doesn't cost the company anything outside of the cost of maintaining the necessary facilities while payment using a credit card does incur a charge on top of that.

Comment: Genuine question: What is the actual problem?  OP only had to pay £5, and taxi accepted £5.  Was the driver unhappy with this or something?

Comment: In the US, I learned that the credit card payment to the driver is delayed "for processing" by the company, and that it can be hard for the driver to track what's been paid them and what's still owed. I've had drivers hold out their own phones for me to swipe my card through, but I won't do the in the future. When I call for a cab, I now firmly say "I'm using a credit card" and the dispatcher often says, "That's fine" in a surprised voice. But-there's never a scuffle at the end. I try to tip in cash.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Everywhere I go, all over the world, the first thing I say when I get in a taxi is "credit card ok?" and sometimes "I have no local currency." [I once accidentally said this in my own country because it's my "set sentence" and it just came out.] This is even before I say where I'm going. Sometimes they say no, it's not ok, and I get right back out and get in another taxi.

You ask if the deal you and your driver arranged is "ok". It was clearly ok with the driver, or he wouldn't have done it. Is it ok with you? You spent less than you otherwise would. Will someone come and complain about you or ask for more money? No, it's over and done with once you got out of the car.

If you were left irritated by it, you could call the taxi company and object, because as you say, they are supposed to take cards. This is probably why the driver went past the 5-pound mark on the meter (there is probably a limit from the company on how much they can be underpaid) and then went even further with the meter off. "Here is a small gift: please don't report me." You could report it anyway, or you could let it go.

I suggest letting it go, but always asking in future before the meter goes on.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of reporting him at all, I was worried he might report me. Last night I was coming from a club, and although I didn't drink much, I just wanted to get home, because it was 5 in the morning, and I was really tired. He said that he doesn't take cards, but the other driver with whom he shres the car does.

Comment: Nonetheless, thank you very much for your answer, it has put my mind somewhat at ease.

Comment: @WadeTyler What would he report you for?  And to who?

Comment: @Midavalo I don't know, I'm not from the UK. I just moved here for university

Comment: This answer seems geared towards areas in which credit cards are not usually or always accepted by cabs. But this driver was *legally required* to accept credit cards. In that context, asking up-front is nothing more than waiving your rights and giving the cabbie the opportunity to illegally refuse you service, forcing you to wait for another cab (whose driver may be no more accommodating than this one). While I sympathize with cab drivers in a great many respects, and try to tip well to very well, that sympathy dies when they try to cheat people. In context, this answer is *wrong*.

Comment: In London, not having an available card payment facility is a breach of a black cab taxi driver's terms of service; he should not be taking fares without the ability to take card payments. Pointing this out will sometimes cause the machine to come back to life.

Comment: @KRyan why do you feel the taxi driver was legally required to take credit cards?

Comment: @MadHatter See the answer by WeatherVane, comment by Calchas, and so on.

Comment: @KRyan I suspect taxis are mandated to take cards most places I go. But sometimes their machines are "broken" and sometimes they're really broken. I waive no rights by asking up front. No card, out I get, no fare for that driver. Period. I get into a cab that will take my card. As for waiting, generally there is another right behind - I tend to get them at taxi ranks rather than hailing on the street. No-one I ever hailed on the street said no they wouldn't take a car.

Comment: @KRyan I think you may be confusion *contractual breach* with *statutory obligation*.  Advertising that you take cards then failing to do so may be the former (though see caveats about *offers to treat*), but it is not the latter.  WV makes an interesting point about *London black cabs*, but sadly the OP asks about Liverpool's cabs, which are not (afaik) thus regulated.

Answer (score 13):

In the UK we have two kinds of taxi: Hackney Carriage, and Private Hire. The former are known in London as "black cabs" and are present in other cities too. They work off the streets by demand, but they may also be saloon cars or minibus conversions. Private Hire must be pre-booked through an agency. The actual distinction is in the vehicle's license conditions and signage.

Now, many Hackney cabs also have a Private Hire account so they can accept bookings too, but if you took that taxi from a rank or hailed it on the street, that is not a contract with the hire car agency.

Having said that, although traditionally taxis are a cash business, the trade is moving forward fast. London's black cabs are now required by law to accept card payments.

Don't worry, the taxi driver will not report you. He made sure the meter was seen to go over £5 because the metered fare is the maximum that may be legally charged (except for out-of-town journeys by pre-arrangement, and by certain well known taxi agencies who manage to sidestep the local legislation).

Answer (score 5):

**There is no problem**

You paid for the journey. You should be happy because the driver gave you a discount on the fare; the driver is happy because they got paid at a rate they were happy with.

Taxi drivers are, usually, free to come to a deal to give you a reduced fare, and there is nothing wrong in this.

Comment: I could see someone being unhappy if they needed the cash.

Answer (score 3):

UK taxis have at least three reasons to not take cards when advertised (even though they should):

- The system that takes cards is linked by a 3G phone, and is sometimes unreliable. If you have no cash, the driver risks not getting paid.
- Drivers are self-employed and thus pay the cost of the credit card transaction (this is normal of the order of a pound or two, plus 2 or 3% of the fare, so not enormous). This is more significant with lower fares.
- Some drivers (shock horror) might not report all their cash earnings for tax, therefore cash fares are worth more.

Personal experience (London not Liverpool): in London black cabs, offering a credit card used to be very unpopular when advertised. The only reliable way to pay for a black cab on a credit card was to use ComCab etc. This appears to have changed (perhaps thanks to Uber and Addison Lee) and now paying even small fares by contactless card doesn't generate a grumble, and contactless machines are pretty prevalent in London cabs.

Comment: The reason cards aren't popular on mainland europe is exactly that the 2-3% fee IS seen as enormous.

Comment: Those would seem to be reasons to not take cards at all, not reasons to advertise that they take cards but then not do so.

Comment: Point #3 is the most known reason why taxidriver associations fight against Uber & similar. For me, the real horror is Governments not taking measures to force taxidrivers to honestly report their earnings as regular employees do. But this goes out of scope and is just a personal comment.

Comment: @PieterB Are you sure about that? 2-3% of £5 is 10-15p, an insignificant amount. However, there is a minimum fee amount, which is why many businesses in the UK only accept cards for amounts above £5: the actual fee paid on a £5 transaction is much more than 2-3%. And, in any case, the question is specifically about the UK, not mainland Europe.

Comment: @djr they are probably fine taking a £70 ride to the airport on a credit card. The way many cabs work (I know London best) is that what's on the cab may not be in the control of the driver - e.g. the driver rents the cab from his friend (who is a also driver) so they get better utilisation of the asset, or signs up to ComCab (or one of the other networks) so gets all their stickers and so forth but actually only wants rides sourced through ComCab to go on a card.

Answer (score 1):

What happened was transactional.  When you said you only had 5 quid and asked to run a credit card, he compared *his interest* in the two options.

Option 1: he only gets 5 quid for the ride, but it's sure cash in his hand.

Option 2: he gets 5.75, and maybe a tip, but has to process it through his credit card (which may be broken) and has a bunch of fees and expenses relating to that, and you don't know those fees. Also it may expose the transaction to his boss who may want a cut, and the government who nay want a cut.  And there is probably a processing delay of a day or ten before he actually gets spendable money.

So he is making a determination of what's best for *him*.  You can rest assured he is looking after his own self-interest, he doesn't know you.

Answer (score -1):

The driver breached their contract in not accepting CCs, demanded cash, knowing the customer didn't have enough, and this caused inconvenience to the customer, and further (it's not 100% clear) dropped them short of their destination.

**Make a complaint to the licensing authority** for your municipality

[**Liverpool City Council online taxi complaint form**](https://contact.liverpool.gov.uk/cus/servlet/ep.app?type=UF297081&srvId=UF297929&ut=X)

Also, it could help if you had a photo of the in-taxi signage that stated they accept CCs.

(You can try complaining to the company too, but they can just ignore you or lie to you or tell you to take a hike - has happened to me. But if you complain to the body wot issues their license and has the power to take it away, believe me you will get their full attention very swiftly.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65892/discussion-on-answer-by-smci-taxi-not-accepting-payment-by-credit-card-although).